# Correct way to structure HTML with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for some time now, structuring my HTML elements without really knowing if I'm doing it in a right way. It works but I would like to know if there is a better way of doing it.

Lets take this template for instance:

[image]

What I do first is that I try to divide the page into smaller pieces. In this case I would start by dividing the left and right column, giving the left column 4 and the right one 8 "columns". I would write and position the HTML/class attributes like this:

```
...
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div id="upperLeftCol" class="col-md-12"> ... </div>
     <div id="lowerLeftCol" class="col-md-12">
          <div id="uniqueId1" class="col-md-12">
              <img src="#" alt="...">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  some messge
              </div>
          </div
          <div id="uniqueId2" class="col-md-12">
              <img src="#" alt="...">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  some messge
              </div>
          </div
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
      .......
  </div
</div>
```

Well you get the picture. I try to divide each subsection as an own div and give it the col-md-12 class attribute since I've noticed it aligns best with the other div that has the same class annotation.

I'm sure there is a more correct way to do this. What is the "best" approach? Also when should I create a new "row"?

Comment: I do pretty much the same - I don't see any way that would be better. It quickly becomes very verbose, but Bootstrap seems to do that.

Comment: Rows line up columns vertically. I would use rows for the container with 4 sections and the container with 3 message-looking-things

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it better suited for CodeReview http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as it is opinion based

Comment: Personally I'd have the left column not in a `.row` with the right column, as they will likely have differing height unless the content is completely static. The purpose of a `.row` is to group things in a vertical section

Comment: Having columns as direct children of other columns without a level of row in between them, as in the above code, is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use more rows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="upperLeftCol" class="col-md-12"> ... </div>
```

The code is better to understanding for others persons and avoid some design errors when you are using dynamic cells.

Comment: I disagree with this

Comment: Laughed at "dinamic"

Comment: Actually adding in rows makes design adherence a nightmare and definitely does not make it easier for other developers to understand.

Comment: When you are making a Bootstrap form you use a form-group div por each form component (similar to set a row) and then you set col-* on label and input. I think the way i said works similar. But, you know... its just my opinion :).